# GraphDB-Lite is not displaying in dropdown list

Tags: tomcat6, sesame, graphdb

I've copied these two files `openrdf-sesame.war` and `openrdf-workbench.war` into `tomcat/webapps` folder.

I goto this url  http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/ 
but **grapdb-lite** is not displayed in dropdown list when creating new repository. what did i miss?

```
version:graphdb-lite-6.1.8410
```

[image]

Comment: I find out the answer, GraphDB (formerly called OWLIM)

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out yourself: GraphDB was formerly known as OWLIM, and in the Sesame Workbench dropdown is still called that. So the option you're looking for is "OWLIM-Lite".

Answer (score 0):

You are using Sesame Workbench where GraphDB appears with its old name OWLIM. 
As of 1st of December 2015 Ontotext officially encourage all GraphDB-Lite users to upgrade to [GraphDB Free](http://ontotext.com/products/graphdb/editions/#lite_edition). In GraphDB Free you will benefit from using native GraphDB Workbench instead of Sesame one.

*I work for Ontotext

Comment: please add proper description.